# Excel: Is it possible to remove row(s) based on if/then conditions

Tags: excel, reporting

Newcomer here.

I have a task I am trying to automate or simplify Report Data in Excel and not sure how to set a formula up or even what to search for to begin building rules for this or where to start or if this is even possible.

*Not even necessarily looking for a complete solution (although that would be great if it is easy), but ideas or advice on how I would start to break this down or what keywords to use to search to learn how to figure out what I need to do here based on my needs below would be awesome. *

[Original Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFIPp.jpg)

In the first photo I attached, I have a part of the report generated by and downloaded from our Learning Management System which tells me employees names and often several statuses* for a specific class (column E is the class "Assessment and Escalation Class") and statuses in Column G include Registered, Completed, No Show, Withdrawn, Registered / Past Due, etc.. I only care if they have fully completed the class or not, and want to remove the unnecessary data in cases such as no show, withdrawn, etc. and say either Complete or Incomplete if have they taken the course (see 2nd photo below for how I want the data to look).

**I need a way to build something like a combination of rule(s), condition(s), etc. to have Excel learn:**

(I am guessing I may need to combine Column A and Column G into their own column an attempt to tie the transcript status to a user) then-

1. If Column A (User Full Name) combined with Column G is ever “completed”, then mark user as “Complete” in Column J and use most recent completion date (from criteria in Column H “Training Start Date”) AND remove any or all additional duplicate entries for this user except the row with the completed status.
2. If Column A (user Full Name) combined with Column G is ever blank/no value, Withdrawn, No Show, and there are any duplicates, then reduce entries for this user to 1* and indicate “Incomplete” in Column J, or just indicate as Incomplete if there is only 1 value.
   *Any of the incomplete entries if there are more than 1 could be left on the report - it doesn’t have to be a specific incomplete status - unless I need to do this for the logic to make sense.

Using the example, I attached how I want the data to look when cleaned up: [Fixed data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNaLt.jpg)

Any ideas? Is something like this possible?

I made a Calculated Field [Calculated Field] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Mw2n.jpg) in our Learning Management system when making the report to mark in a "If Complete" column if they were Complete then they are listed in this column as Complete, and if the transcript status is blank or anything but complete, they are marked as Incomplete. [If Complete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BEPT0.jpg)

However, if I filter by the If Complete column for those who are "Incomplete" it doesn't check to see if they also were ever status Complete and I have to manually check any duplicate values for all the users and see if any are completed and remove anything else or remove multiple incomplete statuses (as you could see in the red highlighted rules in my detail of problem post).

Answer (score 0):

With Excel 2019 and above one of the approaches is to create new "table" using `FILTER`. `B` (instead of `A` (name) will be used as *User ID* is more likely to be unique compared to *Name*), `I` and `J` columns will be used to create a criteria for filtering:

```
=FILTER(A2:J13,I2:I13=(MAXIFS(I2:I13,B2:B13,B2:B13,J2:J13,"Completed")+(COUNTIFS(B2:B13,B2:B13,J2:J13,"Completed")=0)*(MAXIFS(I2:I13,B2:B13,B2:B13,J2:J13,"Incomplete"))))
```

Result (`A16:J19`):

[image]

Explanation of how filter works is in `K:P` columns.